# facebook sdk get email address in php

Tags: php, facebook, email, authentication, sdk

I just customized a Facebook Connect using PHP Sdk. Everything works on my webpage, I can recieve informations, but I can't figure out how to echo the users email adress. I tried following facebook's manual here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/ but can't get it workin. :( Have i overlooked something?

Regards, Simon

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can see if you've indeed overlooked something?

Comment: My issue is that i don't know what code to write, to get the user's email adress :-)

Comment: Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

Comment: tgies-> Thanks for you link. But i'm a little lost. Do i need to change something to work with FQL? Because when trying to echo some of the strings out it does not work. Thanks for you patience!

Comment: ahh found this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/ now it start to make a little more sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have asked permissions for retrieving the email address in your app, or else it wont work:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

echo $user_profile[email];
```

Comment: Hmm now i has changed my permissions under User & Friend Permissions in Facebook. Has typed in only Email. I'm using your code, but still no email is being displayed (I have also logged out and in). Facebook says that change may take several minutes to propagate to all server. But have i done well so far? (permissions)

Comment: If your permissions asked are "email" AND the user is logged in to the app, it works.

Comment: Remove your App from the Apps you use. If you use it again, a login dialog should appear, with asking permission for using your email address.

Comment: I just tried to remove my app ang reauth. But nothing changes in the description for the permissions. It's strange because when i preview the login box the changes for the permissions is there. Should i wait more than 20mins for the changes to appear?

Comment: Not where I am living. Changes are almost immediate.

I suppose your permissions are not properly set in developer app page.

Comment: This is what my settings look like at the moment after changes. Good bad? :-) http://grab.by/iD2K

Comment: Look fine to me... I use the code above on https://apps.facebook.com/balirealestate/ and it works fine. (add something to the wish list and click on "Mail Wish List", and you will see your email address. (No need to really send)

Comment: Nice app! But i'm just wondering why my changes does not appear in the connect dialog like in yours (ex. email request) :/. Could it be because there's some other required fields which need to be filled?